# How long does a business have to give a refund?

Tags: united-states, insurance, california

My dentist's office requires payment upfront, and then they wait to get paid by the insurance. On Yelp, people say that it takes a lot of sweat and tears to get a refund from them. (In my case the insurance paid them almost 2 months ago, and they owe me over $1000 - still no sign of refund).

How long do they have to issue a refund, and can I demand penalties if they take too long?

Comment: Why is the insurance company sending your money to the dentist?

Comment: @User58220: It's not uncommon in the US to pay a doctor up front when it isn't clear how much your insurance will cover, and for them to reimburse you when their payment comes in. It's _more_ common for them to simply wait to bill you until after the insurance has responded, and I would suggest that MaxB drop them a polite letter asking what's going on and saying that he really doesn't want to get consumer protection agencies involved... AND change dental offices immediately. (No, penalties are unlikely unless you go to court. Interest... maybe.)

Comment: Is the dentist in-network or out-of-network?

Comment: Botton line - they owe you money. Consider what they would do if you didn't pay them on time, and do the same. I.e.: threatening letters, lawsuits, collections - the whole thing, including charging late fees and interest after you issued first deadline. Get a good lawyer and nail them.

Comment: @keshlam Admittedly this is in Canada, but when I pay my dentist up front my insurance sends the payment to me, not my dentist. Why should they send it to the dentist? They have their money.

Comment: @keshlam insurance companies usually have contracts which require the provider to bill the insurance company before billing the patient, with the exception of copayments which are due at time of service.  I dealt with this recently where a provider wanted payment up front and said they'd refund any overpayment.  I refused as my insurance company's contract prohibits that since the provider doesn't know how much of my deductible I met.  I got the service without payment at that time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a civil matter, so while they *should* refund your money immediately, you may have to pull some teeth to get them to act. (sorry, couldn't help it)

Send a strong letter requesting payment by a certain date. Something like, "According to ABC insurance, you received payment from them two months ago. I contacted you three times already regarding reimbursement to no avail. I hereby demand reimbursement in the amount of $1000 by Friday, December 19th or I will be forced to take further action."

Might even want to send it certified mail, return receipt requested. That should do it -- a threat of legal action without explicitly saying so should get the point across. I'd expect a check pretty quickly. If it were me and they still don't pay by the deadline, I'd take them to small claims court (no lawyer needed). You won't get interest or penalties, but the costs of small claims court will be included in the judgment. I doubt it goes that far.

Oh, and use Yelp to find another dentist!

Comment: Upvoted, though I'd like to propose deleting "use Yelp to" -- how it's done is less important than doing it, and there are lots of other resources.

Comment: Naming Yelp was supposed to be a bit humorous since OP mentioned that the dentist already has a lousy rep on Yelp. Hindsight, right?

Comment: Ah. Missed that. Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Some insurance companies in the US insist that if the dentist has 
been paid in full by the patient, then any insurance benefits will be
paid directly to the patient and not to the dentist. Others do not
insist, but will send
the insurance benefits to the patient if the dentist's billing
office marks the box saying "Benefits to be paid to the patient"
or something similar. When I am paying the dentist bill (on the way
out from the dentist office), I always remind the person I hand *my*
check to to make sure that I get the reimbursement checks directly
from the insurance company. These checks always arrive some time
later,  and if the check
arrives more than three months late, included is *another* check
for $x.yz as *interest* earned on money due to me.  So, maybe all
that is needed to remind the office about this when making the payment.

This is not to say that a careless data-entry clerk might still not
check the right box, or that the dentist office might be doing what
you are experiencing as a matter of policy: "keep the patient's money
for as long as possible". Also, note that in some
insurance company systems, the date that a claim is marked as
processed and/or paid is *not* the day that the check is in the mail
(or an ACH transfer is made).

If the problem persists, you should consider whether switching
to another dentist with a better and more accommodating billing system
will be better for you.